# Not able to set input file in IE 11

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have file input in dojo grid, I called the function onChange and I have the data in the file object but when I am submiting the form the file content is empty. I also created the dummy input file to set the content of file but it's working in chrome but it's not working in IE, Please see the below code.

document.getElementById('dummyId').files = event.target.files;

Note dummyId is id of temporary input file. It's working in chrome but it's not working in IE. Can you please help me why it's not working in IE.

Please see the below code.

```
<table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" 
                                   data-dojo-id="documentsGrid" selectionMode="none"
                                   data-dojo-props='store: documentsGrid_data,
                                                    keepSelection: true, 
                                                    canEdit: documentsGrid_edition,
                                                    canSort: function(col) {  
                                                        if(col === this.getColumnTogglingItems().length) return false;
                                                            return true;
                                                    },
                                                    autoHeight: true,
                                                    plugins: {
                                                        indirectSelection: {
                                                            noresize: true
                                                        },
                                                        pagination: {
                                                          defaultPageSize : 10,
                                                          sizeSwitch: false
                                                        }
                                                    }'>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th field="documentId" formatter="formatOptions" noresize="true" width="14px"  headerClasses="alignTextLeft" cellClasses="alignTextCenter">
                                            <s:message code="common.input.label.options" />
                                        </th>   
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>


                            <span style="display:none;" id="documentUpload">
                                <input type="file" id="file" onchange="onFileUpload(event, 0);" accept="image/*,application/pdf" style="width : 80px;"/>
                            </span>

                            <input style="display: none;" id="dummyId" name="dummyDocument" type="file" class="width178"/>


                            function formatOptions(rowIdx){
                                var input = dojo.byId('documentUpload').innerHTML   
                                return input;
                            }

                            function onFileUpload(event,idx){
                            document.getElementById('dummyId').files = event.target.files;  
                            }
```

Comment: Have not tried ie in some time. Have you filed a bug? Can you include the complete HTML and JavaScript at the question?

Comment: Try to [use F12 developer tools to check whether it contain some JS error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/bg182326(v%3dvs.85)), then you could add some debugger or set break points in the change function to [debug your JS code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v%3dvs.85)).

Comment: I checked it's not contain any error.

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code, then, using F12 developer tools to debug the code, you can see that the files variable don't contain a file, it means that you didn't set files for the dummyId control.

```
function onFileUpload(event, idx) {
    debugger;
    var value = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('dummyId').files = event.target.files;
    var files = document.getElementById('dummyId').files;
    var files2 = document.getElementById('file').files;
}
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

So, when you want to submit the form, you need to get the upload file from the "file" control, instead of from the temporary input file.

Comment: I tried this one and it's working fine but I have multiple input files and If I am going this way all files have the same content but I don't want same content in all files. I have five input type files and I want to upload different files.